# Battery/alternator? STARTER?

Tags: toyota, corolla

so my car battery died on me yesterday so i had to take my other car to work i got home let and said i would just jump it in the morning as i did it had a clicking sound this morning it took a minute but it started up so i let it set for 10 minutes or so then i got back to my car it was still running then i tried to back up and turn my headlights on and it died ?? i think its my alternator because i checked my car battery about a month ago because i was having the same problem i hooked it up at auto part store and they said everything was good anybody know what could be wrong??

i cleaned The battery poles and the adapters and I got one start out of it then I let it run with my RPMs up around 1500-2000 for about 5-10 minutes then I turned it off and tried again and it didn’t start then I felt the node and it was hot so I think I have a bad starter??

Comment: Chances are, that both the alternator and the battery are in good working order... What seems to be the issue here is a faulty grounding. So, best way of action is to get some sandpaper and clean thoroughly both the poles and the terminals of the battery. If that doesn't fix the issue, you need to start looking for corroded groundings or damaged cables. But most likely are the battery poles...

Answer (score 1):

If the engine is left at tickover - as you say for 10 minutes, then it is not necessarily charging the battery.

If you want it to charge then you should increase the engine speed to 1500 or 2000 rpm, then it will charge at a decent rate.

However, if the battery is defective then all the charging may not help anyway.

Get the battery tested (perhaps give it a proper charge on a good battery charger first) and then have it properly tested to see if it is good or faulty. Also get the charging system tested so that you know what is happening.